# How can automatically determine min and max on pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to delete empty space around graph automatically.my external picture is below graph without green box. I want delete this empty space green box automatically not by using xmax and xmin.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want option `enlargelimits = false`, which turns off the automatic enlargement of the range.

---

The standard setting of `enlargelimits` is `true`, which will automatically enlarges adds a percentage on to the highest/lowest values for both x- and y-axes. I'm afraid I don't know what percentage gets added, but I think it's around 10%. So for example if the maximum x value in the input was 10, the x-axis upper limit would be 11. The over all result is to produce a 'border' around the material.

Setting `enlargelimits = false` means that `pgfplots` sets the limits to the maximum/minimum values in the input. So in my example, the plot would stop at exactly 10.

Other options are to have one limit automatic (settings `upper` and `lower`), or to do things on an axis by axis basis (for example using `enlarge x limits). This is covered in the [pgfplots manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), page 216.